# JS/jQuery return TH of related TD, Possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to know if it's possible to get the `.html()` of a specific TH when it has no id or class set using jQuery selectors.

To illustrate my question:

```
TABLE
    THEAD TR
        TH1 TH2 TH3
    TBODY TR
        TD1 TD2 TD3
```

I set a `$('table tbody tr td')` function that turns a cell into an input field on  a double click, then back into text on blur, reflecting the change made to the cell via the input field.

I need to be able to know which column I am accessing. So if someone double clicks TD2 I want the input field name to contain TH2.

Please let me know how I can do this without setting id/class's for each TH or TD.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the handler is on your `<td>` element, then in your handler:

```
var th = $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq( this.cellIndex );
```

Table cells maintain their own index numbers, accessible through the `cellIndex` property.

Table rows do the same thing via `rowIndex`.

The jQuery methods are:

- the [`closest()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to get the `<table>`
- the [`find()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to find the nested `<th>` elements
- the [`eq()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to reduce the `<th>` elements down to the one at the same index as the `<td>`

A little further jQuery reduction could look like this:

```
var th = $(this).closest('table')[0].rows[0].cells[ this.cellIndex ];
```

Comment: @Jonathan: @Gaby: Thanks. I love those rare examples of browser compliant features that are especially useful like row and cell indexing.

Answer (score 0):

How is this

```
$('td').click(function(){
    cell = this.cellIndex;
    alert( $(this).closest('table').find('th:eq('+cell+')').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery alternative to Patrick's solution could be:

```
$("td").click(function()
{
    var $this = $(this);

    //Find the index of the column based on how many 
    //previous TDs there are.
    var col_idx = $this.prevAll("td").length;

    //Now select the Nth TH in the table using the base 1 column index.
    var $th = $("th:nth-child(" + (col_idx + 1) + ")", $this.closest("table"));

    /* your other code */
});
```